# Recommendation on reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I decided to do some reviewing. On one review edit, I guess I misunderstood what 'Improve' meant. I almost clicked 'Reject' but clicked 'Improve' feeling that either I would fix the edit or that it would get bounced back to the individual that made the edit, it seemed like bad formatting and bad english. I was given a little slapped saying that I failed the 'bad edit' test, when in reality, I was paying attention. Possibly, my misunderstanding of reviewing. Regardless, I think a reminder of what 'Improve' means may be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume the review audit you failed was https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4900512

Assuming that ever happens in a real edit, the problem with this one is that the edit doesn't actually do anything helpful; it's actually just injecting random words in random places. The "proper" action would be to reject as vandalism (and go improve the original post yourself if you think it still needs it).

The general rule of thumb I use is that I only click on "Improve" if the edit itself is *useful, but there's still more of the post to improve*. In the fake scenario that you were given, this isn't the case, since the edit itself doesn't actually help the post. In other words, I use "Improve" for incomplete edits, not bad edits. Bad edits should just be rejected.

Comment: I agree with both @OGHaza and your comments, i'm not entirely sure what I was thinking. I almost clicked 'Reject'. I think if I was brought to another screen on clicking 'Improve' and given the ability to change my mind, I may have gone back and rejected it. Oh well... my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Improve allows you to suggest a further edit on top of the one you are reviewing - it applies the suggested edit, and then applies your edit on top.

Suggested edit audits never do **anything** beneficial for a post, so you should not be trying improve it, it should be flat out rejected.

If you look at the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4900512) again, it's very clear that it defaces the post.

It changes the opening line from

> The old version of redis client for c# were using commands like

to

> The standard events on old version of redis client for c# were asking you ll useful that an commands public void setselectprice double